# Vite to combine multiple files to multiple specific named files?

Tags: javascript, webpack, bundle, vite, rollup

The structure is as follows:

```
 - ChunkFolder
     - Subchunk1
           - [js & scss files]
           - page
               - Y
                   - [js & scss files]
               - X
                   - [js & scss files]
      - Subchunk2
           - [js & scss files]
           - page
               - Y
                   - [js & scss files]
               - Z
                   - [js & scss files]
      - ...
      - SubchunkN
 - Resources Folder
     - [js & scss files]
```

And the output should be:

```
 - main[hash].js|css
 - chunk[hash].js|css (combined of all the ones directly under Folder1 - FolderN)
 - page
    - pageX[hash].js|css
    - pageY[hash].js|css
```

Basically we have an 3 different levels:

- app (app.js|css)
- "chunk" (chunk.js|css) - combined from Subchunk1 - SubchunkN direct assets
- pages (page-X.js|css, page-Y.css|js, page-Z.css|js etc) - combines all different page assets per page (pages can be in multiple separate Subchunk folders).

This was done with webpack by collecting all JS files into a separate folder (copying out from Chunk with direct items in one folder, all pages grouped by page folder) and for style we made an entrypoint file with the collected filenames with data "@import x...". While not pretty, it worked.

While I can create the same entry point files for styles to combine them, the main problem is for JS. I cannot seem to find a way to combine them the way I need to and keep the proper names.

Another important issue was that some JS files have functions, listeners etc, while some subchunk JS files have classes - it didn't want to include those classes.

Some help would be appreciated as I am new to vite. While I get one part seemingly working, then another breaks...